# Columns of text in NSMenu?

Tags: cocoa, nsmenu, tabstop

Is there a way to make an NSMenu whose content looks something like this:

```
1  one     uno
2  two     dos
3  three   tres
4  four    quatro
```

(Short of specifying a monospace font in the item AttributedText, that is.)

Comment: I don't really understand what your question is. If it's simply about changing the font, then you can set the `NSMenu.font` property to your monospace font.

Comment: I want the columnar layout, without using a monospace font.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a custom view for your menu items which basically allows you to display whatever you want in your menu, including multiple columns of text.

See [this example](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/ViewsInMenuItems.html) from Apple for instance.